# Install4j - Is there a way to programmatically disable detection of previous installation?

Tags: install4j

**"Detect previous installation directory" is on**
**"Alert for update installation"** is on

Is there a way to disable those programmatically under certain circumstances?
By default I still want to keep them enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some trials and errors found this workaround:

```
context.setInstallationDirectory(new File("some directory different from existing installation"))
```

This will force installer not to trigger "update existing installation" sequence.
Should be executed before welcome screen, e.g. in startup.

What didn't work:

- Setting `sys.confirmedUpdateInstallation=false`, "Update alert" component will ignore it and override it to `true`
- "Update alert" component cannot be disabled through its initialization or visibility scripts, it just completely ignores those. (a bug?)